# Spanish for "burn": "quemar" vs "prender"

Tags: traducción, vocabulario

The dictionary says both mean "to burn". Obviously there must be some difference, subtle or otherwise. What are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all note that **burn** means different things in English:

1. Catch fire.
2. Be consumed by fire.
3. Make something to burn.

**Quemar** is just **burn**, in with meaning 3. Meaning 2 will be **quemarse** or **arder**.

**Prender**, however, means to **catch fire** (meaning 1), **put in flame**, that is, the act of start burning. It is sometimes used redundantly: **prender fuego**.

For example, you can say:

```
La madera mojada no prende bien. - Wet wood doesn't catch fire easily.
```

But if you say

```
La madera verde no arde bien. - Green wood doesn't burn easily.
```

The meaning is subtly different:  the former means that it is difficult to start a fire with wet wood; the latter means that wet wood does not give great flames.

But with the following phrase:

```
¡Los pirómanos quieren prender fuego al mundo! - Pyromaniacs want to burn down the world.

¡Los pirómanos quieren quemar el mundo! - Pyromaniacs want to burn down the world.
```

The meaning is practially the same.

Note that **prender**, as is, without **fuego** following may require some context, because this word has a lot of different meanings.

The meaning of **prender** as **turn on** an electrical device sounds regional, from America, I think.

Comment: "La madera verde no arde bien. - Green wood doesn't burn easily."...what is "arde"?

Comment: @AmitSchandillia: Oh, sorry. __Arder__ is __to get burn__. Synonim with __quemarse__. __Quemar__ is __to make burn__, if I explain myself... In English, if I burn a match, the matches burns. In Spanish, _yo quemo/prendo/enciendo una cerilla, la cerilla arde/se quema_. I'll add this to the answer.

Comment: Wow, that's a new word I learned today! And you explained it really well. Thanks!

Comment: You have two options `To burn the fire` or `To turn on the fire`... which one would you choose?

Comment: @dockeryz: Do you mean in English? I would say `to burn the house`, `to turn on the light`, but `to start the fire`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **quemar** and **prender** for the verb "to burn".

However, prender is used to "turn on" something, like:

```
Prender la luz - To turn on the light
Prender el horno - To turn on the oven
```

Besides, you can use **encender**; so you can

```
Encender la luz
Encender el horno
```